# Expose mount from LXC to host

Tags: mount, posix, lxc

I am working with a proprietary POSIX client to mount a network directory. The packages provided by the vendor are horrible (e.g., post-install that does `ln -sf /usr/bin/fusermount`?!), so I'm trying to isolate them within an LXC container. I've got the container up and running and the mounting works just fine.

Now I need to make that mount that's in the container available on the host.

I know I can do this using sshfs from the host into the container, but that seems overly-complex. It would be awesome if I could make that mount available without using ssh.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Considering using a [namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/namespaces.7) can sometimes involve doing [other mounts](https://manpages.debian.org/namespaces.7#The_/proc/%5Bpid%5D/ns/_directory) and also that once entering a mount namespace all commands are not hosts' commands anymore, the [mount namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/mount_namespaces.7) isn't as easy to handle as others. Instead there's a direct access provided via [`/proc`](https://manpages.debian.org/proc.5#Files_and_directories):

> - `/proc/[pid]/root`
>     UNIX and Linux support the idea of a per-process root of the filesystem, set by the chroot(2) system call. This file is a symbolic
>     link that points to the process's root directory, and behaves in the
>     same way as exe, and fd/*.
>     Note however that **this file is not merely a symbolic link. It provides the same view of the filesystem (including namespaces and
>     the set of per-process mounts) as the process itself.**

It's followed by a mount namespace example.

So one has to look at a process belonging to this container (more exactly its mount namespace component). For a container called *container*, LXC will give the container's (more exactly its pid namespace's) init (pid 1) process' view (in the hosting namespace) with `lxc-info -H -p -n container`.

```
PID1=$(lxc-info -H -p -n container)
CONTAINERMOUNT=/proc/$PID1/root
```

As long as the container is running this directory can be used to access the mount namespace. For example to sort-of backup the container without the dynamic parts:

```
cd $CONTAINERMOUNT
tar -cf /root/backup.tar --exclude='./dev/*' --exclude='./proc/*' --exclude='./run/*' --exclude='./sys/*' .
```

Three remarks after some tests:

- Attempting to bind mount this directory won't work
- One might want to have no activity and a stopped container before accessing the files (eg the backup above). After `cd "$CONTAINERMOUNT"`, the mount namespace resource is not really held: when the container disappears (even with a `kill -KILL $PID1`), the mount namespace will still disappear.
- What *does* work, is mounting from the dedicated [nsfs pseudo-filesystem](https://manpages.debian.org/namespaces.7#The_/proc/%5Bpid%5D/ns/_directory) the mount namespace reference before killing the container (using `lxc-stop -k -n container` or `kill -KILL $PID1` to avoid normal unmount at container's shutdown).

  ```
  cd $CONTAINERMOUNT
  mkdir /root/ns
  touch /root/ns/mnt
  mount --bind /proc/$PID1/ns/mnt /root/ns/mnt
  lxc-stop -k -n container
  ```

  The container's mount namespace is still there with this, until a `umount /root/ns/mnt`. One could leave the directory and access the mount namespace again using `nsenter --mount=/root/ns/mnt ...` but then commands would be from the container. If a `sleep` can be run from it, this would work:

  ```
  nsenter --mount=/root/ns/mnt sleep 10 & sleep 1; cd /proc/$!/root
  ```